# What's the difference between $varName and _varName in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When you work with property wrappers you have access to both `$varName` and `_varName` and I don't really get the difference. For example, here

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var varName: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $varName) //here you can also use `_varName`
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView(varName: .constant("Hello world!"))
  }
}
#endif
```

you can use both `$varName` and `_varName`. The two solutions seem to be equivalent. Both variables are `Binding<String>`. But if I need something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var varName: String

    init(varName: Binding<String>) {
        self.$varName = varName //ERROR
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $varName)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView(varName: .constant("Hello world!"))
  }
}
#endif
```

I'll get an error:

> Cannot assign to property: '$varName' is immutable

and I have to use `_varName` in order to suppress the error:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var varName: String

    init(varName: Binding<String>) {
        self._varName = varName //this works fine
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: _varName)
    }
}
```

They are still both `Binding<String>`, so why won't the former solution work? According to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/415/) the compiler will turn a property wrapper into two things. This:

```
@Binding var varName: String
```

becomes:

```
//Compiler-synthesized code
var $varName = Binding<String> = Binding<String>()

public var varName: String {
    get { $varName.wrappedValue }

    set { $varName.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

`$varName` should be `var`, so why the error above? And, above all, what is that `_varName`? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The synthesized `_varName` property is a stored, settable property that holds (in your case) an instance of `Binding<String>`.

The `varName` property is mapped to the wrapper's `wrappedValue` property. [`Binding` declares `wrappedValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/3335811-wrappedvalue) like this:

> ```
> var wrappedValue: Value { get nonmutating set }
> ```

Since `wrappedValue` is declared with `nonmutating set`, the synthesized `varName` property is always settable (even when `self` is not mutable).

The synthesized `$varName` property is mapped to the wrapper's `projectedValue` property, if the wrapper has a `projectedValue` property. [`Binding` declares `projectedValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/3345090-projectedvalue) like this:

> ```
> var projectedValue: Binding<Value> { get }
> ```

Since `projectedValue` is only declared `get`, not `get set`, you can never assign to `$varName`.

`Binding` doesn't **need** to provide a `projectedValue` property, since you can use `_varName` to get the `Binding<String>` object. The reason `Binding` declares a `projectedValue` property is to make the `$` prefix work the same way for `Binding` as it does for `State`, `ObservedObject`, and `EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: Thanks Rob, now I get why I was making confusion here. As soon as I have time I'll add more details to explain this mistake better.